# Writting to txt file in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I am currently working on a project and I need to write numbers to a file. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
    keyHolder dw ?  
    filename db 'drawlog.txt',0
    filehandle dw ?
    ErrorMsg db 'Error', 13, 10,'$'

proc OpenFile
    mov ah, 3Dh
    mov al, 2
    mov dx, offset filename
    int 21h
    jc openerror
    mov [filehandle], ax
    ret
    openerror:
        mov dx, offset ErrorMsg
        mov ah, 9h
        int 21h
        ret
endp OpenFile

proc closeFile
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    int 21h
    ret
endp closeFile

proc writeKeyToFile
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, offset keyHolder
    int 21h
    mov cx,1
    mov ah, 40h
    mov dl, 13
    int 21h
    mov cx,1
    mov ah,40h
    mov dl, 10
    int 21h
    ret
endp writeKeyToFile
```

The code is sort of working, but there are two things I would like to ask. First, after the write happens the file includes what should have been written and other weird symbols. Second, how can I go down a line when I want to (when writing to the file)?

Comment: Please don't keep changing the question based on the info you get. You can however __add__ to the question as long as you clearly state that it is indeed an addition.

Answer (score 1):

> after the write happen the file include what should have been written and other weird symbols

You are specifying that 16 bytes should be written (`mov cx, 16` - I'm assuming this is DOS, though you don't mention). The address that you specify is only a 2-byte variable. The following 14 bytes presumably contain values that weren't meant to be written to the file.

If `keyHolder` actually represents a string, don't declare it as a "word" (`dw`) - it is a sequence of bytes. (Can you even be sure that 2 bytes is enough to represent the number that you are trying to write?)

> the second thing is how can I go down a line when I want to(when writing to the file)

Write a Carriage return + Line feed sequence (CRLF; byte value 13 followed by 10).

Comment: Thanks you so much, I played a bit with that and everything is working! thanks!

Comment: `dw` is "data word", 16 bits.  `dd` is "data dword", `db` is "data byte".  Or maybe the initial `d` stands for define, I'm not sure on the origin.  Anyway, you can reliably determine the contents of the bytes following `keyHolder`, since this is asm, and `filename` follows immediately after.  "variables" are a high level concept.  In asm, there's just memory or registers.  Some assemblers, like MASM, will infer operand sizes based on the `db` / `dw` / `dd` following a label, though, for instructions using the label in a memory address.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, "can't reliably determine" was a bad choice of words (re-worded now). Too long since I've used MASM and most times I do delve into assembly it's at least 32-bit, so I got confused about the sizes, but you're right of course. Oddly though, as `filename` follows the `keyHolder` variable I would expect that it would be written to the file rather than "weird symbols"; I suspect OP's pasted code is not complete and that there are other variables in between.

Comment: Agreed, I scratched my head about the "weird symbols" for the same reason while writing that comment.  I figured the OP had a different bug or something.  I have no interest in learning DOS system calls, though, to actually see if the OP was calling them correctly.  Good point that the OP may have not actually shown us the code he ran; I've def. seen that kind of thing before.

Comment: @davmac I tried to play with the code a bit today and I when I write specific values I still get "weird symbols" (example singal digit numbers or [ ]) and I was not able to go down a line(I updated the code).

Comment: @Cake int 21h/function 40h writes _from a buffer_ to a file. It seems like you should know this since you use it correctly to write from `keyHolder`, but then immediately after you are loading single byte values into the `dl` register. The `dx` register must contain the _address_ of a buffer. By loading values into `dl` you are generating addresses to a buffer you haven't set up, which is why you're getting "weird symbols". Set up a buffer which contains the bytes 13 and 10 and write _from that buffer_, i.e set `dx` to the address of the buffer, just as you do for `keyHolder`.

Comment: @davmac okay I'll fix that, but sometimes when the `keyHolder` Holds a char like '2','3','4' or '[',']' and then I am writing to the file, it will be written as "weird symbols"

Answer (score 0):

`keyHolder` is not initialized in your code. In order to pass to a new line in the file, declare this variable:

```
    newline db '\r\n'
```

Then write it to the file after you write `keyHolder`. So, the `writeKeyToFile` function becomes:

```
proc writeKeyToFile
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx, 16
    mov dx, offset keyHolder
    int 21h
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx, 2
    mov dx, offset newline
    int 21h
ret
```

Comment: @Cake: If the answers solved your problem, you should click the check-mark under the vote arrows on one of them, to mark it as accepted.

Comment: You say that `newline` should be `'\n'` followed by 0, and that both these bytes should be written to the file (`mov cx, 2`). But on MS-DOS a line end sequence is normally '\r\n' (13, 10), and certainly doesn't include a nul byte.